# 100% width non-responsive HTML layout collapse when window resize

Tags: html, css, layout, fixed-width

How to avoid 100% width non-responsive HTML layout collapse when window resize? I tried by removing viewport meta tag but not working..

Comment: Share your code or  replicate the issue in jsfiddle

Comment: So you would like your `div` to not resize? I'm just a little confused.

Comment: my concern is to avoid the collapsing of 100% width layout when window resize...how can i share code

Comment: Go to [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net) website, hit save once you've pasted your code in and add the link to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just give your body or a container div a set width or min width

```
<body>
<div style="min-width:1024px;" >
//put the rest of your html in here
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign a `width` or `max-width` in your CSS. For example:

```
<body>
    <div id="myContent">Stuff</div>
</body>
```

then in your CSS:

```
#myContent {
    margin:0 auto;
    max-width:1024px;
}
```

The `margin` property will apply a top and bottom margin of `0`, then automatically center the `div` with `auto`. If the browser screen is wider than 1024px, the webpage will not get any larger but will sit in the center of the browser. If it is below 2014, the width will stick to 100% and the content will wrap to fit on the screen.

If your site needs to work in IE6, be sure to specify `width` instead of `max-width`, as IE6 doesn't recognise `max-width` and will just ignore it altogether. You can place this either in an IE-only stylesheet.